# Questions regarding the structure of a mobile payments screen

Tags: gui-design, mobile-application

I am currently working on the payments process of my mobile application. Before asking my questions, I wanted to give a brief overview of what I have done so far.

---

**Payment Summary**

On this screen, the customer receives a brief overview of how much the service they have booked will cost.

[image]

**Add New Card**

Appears once the customer clicks on the *Add Card* button on the **Payment Summary** screen.

[image]

**Remove Card**

Appears once the customer clicks on the *Remove Card* button on the **Payment Summary** screen.

[image]

**Payment Confirmation**

Appears once the customer clicks on the **Pay** button on the **Payment Summary** screen, after filling in all the correct details.

[image]

---

**Question**

How would I restructure the **Payment Summary** so that it relays the following information points effectively back to the customer:

1) The deposit will be taken from the customer's account immediately.

2) The service fee will be taken from the customer's account immediately after the time/date which the service (e.g. an appointment for a haircut) is consumed.

3) The discount is adjustable, and is based on the customer's accumulated free credits (measured in £'s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR: A confirmation email would be a better choice for relaying this info instead of directly on the Payment Summary screen**

---

**Question 1 & 2:**

> 1) The deposit will be taken from the customer's account immediately.
>
> 2) The service fee will be taken from the customer's account immediately after the time/date which the service (e.g. an appointment for a haircut) is consumed.

Under most circumstances, the Payment Summary screen on a mobile screen should be kept simple. At the end of the day, I, as the customer, know £7 will be charged on my credit card. Both deposit and service fee charges will likely show up in the same monthly bill (going with the assumption these are quick appointments scheduled within the next few weeks). So providing this info on the mobile screen isn't terribly helpful. I wouldn't be reading it then.

A common and standard courtesy for e-commerce is to email the customer when the payment is actually taken. This gives me something for record tracking because as an app user, I'm definitely not going to remember the verification code that's shown once to me on screen. This is especially true, because you're making 2 separate charges. If I review my credit card bill and see 2 charges, I want to know where they came from.

The first confirmation email goes out immediately when the deposit is taken. The email should explain the details including the fact only the deposit is taken and the service fee charge will follow when the service is rendered.

The second confirmation email goes out when you take the service fee charge. As a bonus, if you have a rate the service provider feature, you might consider linking to that at the end of this email. This will complete the feedback loop and bring the user back into your app.

---

**Question 3:**

> 3) The discount is adjustable, and is based on the customer's accumulated free credits (measured in £'s).

As a customer, why would I choose a smaller discount?

If the discount amount has to be adjustable, then what you have shown in the UI is fine. It would make sense to default it to the max discount for the user.